# Using TagProperty in Caliburn.Micro ActionMessage

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I my WPF application I use Caliburn.Micro. In SampleView I have code like that

```
<Button Tag="1" Content="Execute" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Execute]"/>
```

of course in SampleViewModel i have method lokks like that:

```
public void Execute() {
    //do something
}
```

but now I want to pass to Execute method value from TagProperty and the only solution I found (in xaml) is:

```
<Button Content="Execute" Tag="1" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Execute($source})]"/>
```

and in ViewModel:

```
public void Execute(FrameworkElement elem) {
    var tag=elem.Tag;
    //do something
}
```

In my opinion using FrameworkElement in ViewModel is bad practice. Maybe someone know better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$this.Tag should work for you in your Execute method could be just an object type convert it down to what you need (string?).

```
public void Execute(object p){
   if(p != null){ 
     var tag = (string)p;
   }
}
```